# Why am I getting UV distortion on a flat surface?

Tags: uv

I have marked a seam around the entire border of a surface and when unwrapping I'm seeing odd distortion and scaling issues.

I've recorded my mesh to show the [issue](https://gfycat.com/SlimyYearlyIndigowingedparrot#?speed=0.5).

As you can see, there is distortion in the middle of the face and a scaling error in the bottom right "leg".

I have averaged and packed the UV. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: To accurately tell, what's wrong .blend file or image of UV layout in UV/Image editor would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a nearly undistorted UV, the modeling topology should be made by even quads, with every pole made only of 4 edges (5 and 3 where strictly necessary), which is not your case. Anyway, as the surface is flat, you can set the 3D view in a front ortographic perspective, select all the faces of the flat surface and press U "Project from view" and you will get an undistorted UV. Then you can select all the UV islands in the UV editor and average and pack everything.

Comment: Thank you, projecting the flat surface gives me a perfect UV map!