# How to display a projected texture on a mesh?

Tags: uv, modifiers, documentation, project

I'm working with [UV Project modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) in Blender 2.81a but can't achieve the exepected result as shown on the documentation page. I've [seen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121210/camera-projection-without-generating-uvs) [other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70717/projecting-texture-onto-surface-from-point/71334#71334) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141491/why-is-the-image-on-the-mesh-warped-while-using-the-uv-project-modifier) regarding the Project modifier but all seems to have it work out of the box.

Taking the [example project](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/File:Uvproject.blend) I don't see the texture applied to Suzanne. I've tried to change the viewport shading to no avail. 
I tried both with and without applying the modifier on Suzanne first.

Which settings should I use in my view port to see the projected image on my mesh object?

Additionaly, I tried to visualize the projected UV map but the `UV Editing` workspace does not display any UV map. I tried to unwrap different objects (which work in a virgin project) but I didn't manage to see or play with any UV map.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Watch this series of videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz4qV5_zuMo&vl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example project seems to be a bit outdated, I took it and added a shader with a checkerboard texture, that works fine - all other settings do indeed work in that file. Just add this shader network to the monkey:

[image]

Then you can change the mapping by moving the projector, which in this project is the lamp.

Comment: Not sur to get what you mean by "changing the mapping". I only get the checker texture applied to Suzanne and not from the Lamp perspective. Shouldn't I be using the `UV Map` input node?

Comment: See in the picture above, it is using UV coordinates indeed. You can also use the UV Map input node, that gives the same result in this case. What happens to the texture on Suzanne when you move the lamp?

Comment: Oh, you are correct! Didn't try it this way! But why is the back of Suzanne also textured? I would have expected it to be black as the projection can't reach it.

Comment: Ah, nice! The projection "goes through" the whole object, so all backsides and obstructed parts get textured as well.

Comment: Ok! Is there any way to disable the "goes through" property? It seems at least in the [example](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) some parts of Suzanne are black.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. It's the same if you use "project from view", so I don't have a solution for that part from the top of my head, sorry. In the example, the black parts are shadows :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102982/discussion-between-vwvw-and-tobkum).